# Looping through array and assigning new array's key

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I am trying to create a new array with it's key being the index of the old array

```
var array = [
          {"tom": "red", "part":"green", "brow_id":45},
          {"tom": "red", "part":"yellow", "brow_id":1},
          {"tom": "red", "part":"yellow", "brow_id":2},
          {"tom": "maroon", "part":"cyan", "brow_id":45}
           ];
var newarray = {};

array.forEach(function(elem) {
        newarray[elem.brow_id] = elem;
                    });
```

The newly formed array is like this

```
         45: {"tom": "red", "part":"green", "brow_id":45},
         1:  {"tom": "red", "part":"yellow", "brow_id":1},
         2:  {"tom": "red", "part":"yellow", "brow_id":2},
```

I want it to contain all the id's of the old array like this

```
        45: [{"tom": "red", "part":"green", "brow_id":45},{"tom": "maroon", "part":"yellow", "brow_id":45}]
         1:  {"tom": "red", "part":"yellow", "brow_id":1},
         2:  {"tom": "red", "part":"yellow", "brow_id":2},
```

What's wrong?

Comment: later you have a mixed reuslt of single objects and arrays with objects.

Comment: if u notice , `newly formed array` u saying is just an object .

Comment: @NinaScholz I just want a multi-dimensional array in index 45, doesn't matter if it's an object or array . Is there any chance to work by assigning as my code does

Comment: Curiosity, why was accepted other answer and not mine?  Just to know.

Comment: @Ele because array.reduce doesn't work in my code. Nina's code worked

Comment: Did you see my answer? Well, was just curiosity.  Have a good day!

Comment: @Ele sorry, I didn't see the updated answer, I will check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the property is given and assign the element, otherwise check for array and if not create an array. Later push the element.

```js
var array = [{ tom: "red", part: "green", brow_id: 45 }, { tom: "red", part: "yellow", brow_id: 1 }, { tom: "red", part: "yellow", brow_id: 2 }, { tom: "maroon", part: "cyan", brow_id: 45 }],
    object = {};

array.forEach(function(elem) {
      if (!object[elem.brow_id]) {
          object[elem.brow_id] = elem;
          return;
      }
      if (!Array.isArray(object[elem.brow_id])) {
          object[elem.brow_id] = [object[elem.brow_id]];
      }
      object[elem.brow_id].push(elem);
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `reduce` to group and build the desired output.

```js
var array = [{    "tom": "red",    "part": "green",    "brow_id": 45  },  {    "tom": "red",    "part": "yellow",    "brow_id": 1  },  {    "tom": "red",    "part": "yellow",    "brow_id": 2  },  {    "tom": "maroon",    "part": "cyan",    "brow_id": 45  }];

var result = array.reduce((a, elem) => {
  if (a[elem.brow_id]) {
    if (Array.isArray(a[elem.brow_id])) a[elem.brow_id].push(elem);
    else a[elem.brow_id] = [elem, a[elem.brow_id]];
  } else a[elem.brow_id] = elem; 
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Using your approach with `forEach` with a fix to check already added elements to the new object.

```js
var array = [{    "tom": "red",    "part": "green",    "brow_id": 45  },  {    "tom": "red",    "part": "yellow",    "brow_id": 1  },  {    "tom": "red",    "part": "yellow",    "brow_id": 2  },  {    "tom": "maroon",    "part": "cyan",    "brow_id": 45  }];

var newarray = {};

array.forEach(function(elem) {
  if (newarray[elem.brow_id]) {
    if (Array.isArray(newarray[elem.brow_id])) newarray[elem.brow_id].push(elem);
    else newarray[elem.brow_id] = [elem, newarray[elem.brow_id]];
  } else newarray[elem.brow_id] = elem;  
});

console.log(newarray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The updated code works, but is it possible to check if the `newarray` has only arrays inside it, and if there are single elements like `"tom": "red",    "part": "yellow",    "brow_id": 1` assign it to have an array and 0th element will have `"tom": "red",    "part": "yellow",    "brow_id": 1`

Comment: @JohnDoe can you post that requirement within the question's body?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping using `Array.forEach()`:

```js
var array = [{"tom":"red","part":"green","brow_id":45},{"tom":"red","part":"yellow","brow_id":1},{"tom":"red","part":"yellow","brow_id":2},{"tom":"maroon","part":"cyan","brow_id":45}];

var result = {};

array.forEach(function(o) {
  var key = o['brow_id'];
  
  result[key] = key in result ? [].concat(result[key], o) : o;
});

console.log(result);
```